# how to display kendo inline editor toolbar by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo inline editor.I want to display editor toolbar initially,and I want to display the toolbar always.and  fix the toolbar inside the editor instead of pop-up toolbar displaying out side.
For the above,
To display the toolbar by default,I put like

```
$(".k-window-titleless.k-editor-widget").show();
```

but it is not displaying initially,
after that,To display the toolbar inside editor,
I gave like

```
.k-editor-inline{
    padding: 70px 5px 40px;
}
```

with this,height increased,but I am not able to display toolbar inside editor.
how to fix these?

Comment: Not getting what you are trying to achieve. Please create a fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kendo build in [focus](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/editor#methods-focus) method to display the editor.

http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@vojtiik/eLaW

```
<div id="topEditor">
                    <h2>
                        Comprehensive HTML5/JavaScript framework <br />
                        for modern web and mobile app development
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Kendo UI is everything professional developers need
                        to build HTML5 sites and mobile apps. Today, productivity
                        of an average HTML/jQuery developer is hampered by
                        assembling a Frankenstein framework of disparate
                        JavaScript libraries and plug-ins.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Kendo UI has it all: rich jQuery-based widgets,
                        a simple and consistent programming interface,
                        a rock-solid DataSource, validation, internationalization,
                        a MVVM framework, themes, templates and the list goes on.
                    </p>
                </div>


  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
                  var target =  $("#topEditor").kendoEditor({
                        tools: [
                            "bold",
                            "italic",
                            "underline",
                            "strikethrough",
                            "justifyLeft",
                            "justifyCenter",
                            "justifyRight",
                            "justifyFull"
                        ]
                    }).data("kendoEditor");

                 target.focus();

                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Given that kendoUIdojo is sort of new, the example didn't work for me in FF - try fullscreen worked fine : http://trykendoui.telerik.com/fullscreen/eLaW

Comment: hi,It works fine,by default editor toolbar is displaying.can we display this toolbar inside the editor.

Comment: If you do so it will cover your content. Why don't you create other <div> around your editor, give it some border and remove border from the editor, then it will visually look as its inside.

Comment: I gave like <div style="border:1px solid black;height:auto;">
    <div contentEditable  id="Editor" data-bind="value:About" onblur="contentblur()"  style="width:97.7%;border:none;"></div> 
</div> .but it editor toolbar displaying out of border only.

Comment: you are missing padding - http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@vojtiik/eLaW/2 just tweak the padding left and right to make it fancy.

Comment: the wrapper : ` <div style="border:1px solid red; padding: 50px;"> `

Comment: Is there any alternative for display toolbar other than focus() method.because I have editor inside list view which contain text box.initially I have to put focus on textbox .so alternation for this.and one more thing is always toolbar has to display (when we click on outside also it has to display)

Comment: I am sure there are alternatives, yet `focus()` method with a context of specific widget is different from javascript generic control `focus()`, they can't interfere. Did you try ?

Comment: yah,I have tried.focus is coming to editor,my focus is diverted from textbox to editor

Comment: Did you consider inverting the order ? The editor widget will remove focus from any control within its scope. Do the editor first and then the text box. http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@vojtiik/eLaW/3